# What is the purpose of the const_cast<> on a volatile?

Tags: c++, casting, standards, volatile

I saw it was possible to do it but I do not understand the interest.

Comment: Are you asking about casting from a `const volatile` to a `volatile` or something else?

Comment: Learned something new about the volatile casting being done with const_cast, and moved my accidentally off-topic (but related) answer to valid scenarios for const_casting here: http://hostilefork.com/2010/06/12/when-should-one-use-const_cast-anyway/

Answer (score 5):

`const` and `volatile` sound like they refer to the same idea on a variable, but they don't.  A `const` variable can't be changed by the current code.  A `volatile` variable may be changed by some outside entity outside the current code.  It's possible to have a `const volatile` variable - especially something like a memory mapped register - that gets changed by the computer at a time your program can't predict, but that your code is not allowed to change directly.  You can use `const_cast` to add or remove `const` or `volatile` ("cv-qualification") to a variable.

Answer (score 4):

`const` and `volatile` are orthogonal.

`const` means the data is read-only.

`volatile` means the variable could be changing due to external reasons so the compiler needs to read the variable from memory each time it is referenced.

So removing `const` allows you to write what was otherwise a read-only location (the code must have some special knowledge the location is actually modifiable).  You shouldn't remove `volatile` to write it because you could cause undefined behavior (due to 7.1.5.1/7 - `If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of an lvalue
with a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behaviour is undefined.`)

Comment: `const_cast` applies to both `const` and `volatile`, and while potentially removing `volatile` can cause undefined behavior, there are cases where it does not. I.e. adding memory barriers will force the compiler into not caching the variable and provides a stronger guarantee that `volatile` (not only the variable will not be cached, but it instruction will not be reordered outside of the critical section).